# Is it bad practice for my server to fetch content from my CDN - rather than S3

Tags: cdn

I want to run a batch process, processing all the media I'm storing behind a CDN, on S3.
I could access S3 directly with my servers S3 credentials, or go via my CDN, thoughts?
Using the CDN would be faster, right? But would is the CDN only supposed to be used by external users?

Comment: If the batch process is on Aws as well, S3 is almost certainly faster.

Comment: @user1937198 my server and storage are in different networks / systems

Comment: Where the server and where the primary storage are are probably key details to add to your question.